# python kernel dead when performing SVD on a sparse symmetrical matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, text-mining, word-count, svd

I would like to reproduce the SVD method mentioned in a standford lecture on my own dataset. The slide of the lecture is as following

[image: stanford lecture]

My dataset is of the same type, which is a word co-occurrence matrix M with a size of

```
<13840x13840 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>' 
with 597828 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

generated and processed from CountVectorizer(), note that this is a symmetric matrix.

However, when I tried to extract features from SVD, however, none of the following code works,

## 1st try:

```
scipy.linalg.svd(M)
```

I have tried the matrix from sparse csr todense() and toarray(), my computer taken quite a few minutes, and it displays kernel stops. I also played around with different parameter settings

## 2nd try:

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(M)
```

I have also tried to change the matrix type from int64 to float64, however, the kernel dead after 30 seconds or so.

Anyone could suggest me a way to conduct SVD on this matrix in any way?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the matrix is to stressful for the memory. You have several options:

1. Perform an adaptive SVD,
2. Use [modred](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/modred),
3. Use the SVD from [dask](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/06/26/Complex-Graphs).

The latter two should work out of the box.
All these options will load only what the memory can.

Comment: in fact after i installed the dask package, the above code becomes much faster even i'm not using a dask svd function. Any thoughts why?